# SQL query, what Items are in a bucket?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem similar to this one:

I have a DB table like :

```
 ╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦════════╗ 
 ║ ID ║ Bucket Name ║ Item Name ║ action ║ 
 ╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬════════╣ 
 ║  1 ║ B_a         ║ item1     ║ insert ║ 
 ║  2 ║ B_a         ║ item2     ║ insert ║ 
 ║  3 ║ B_b         ║ item1     ║ insert ║ 
 ║  4 ║ B_b         ║ item1     ║ remove ║ 
 ║  5 ║ B_a         ║ item1     ║ remove ║ 
 ║  6 ║ B_a         ║ item3     ║ insert ║
 ╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

With an SQL query I want to get the current status of each bucket:

```
 ╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦
 ║ Bucket Name ║ items         ║
 ╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬
 ║ B_a         ║ item2, item3  ║
 ║ B_b         ║ NULL          ║
 ╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩
```

I know I can select each row and and go over the output to find the status of each bucket, but I am looking for a solution using a SQL query.
How can I do that?

I am currently using MySql, but sql-server is also an option.

Comment: I don't think `item1` should be in bucket `B_a'`; `item2` should be.

Answer (score 1):

This is an aggregation query with a few twists.  In MySQL, it is not so hard:

```
select bucketname, group_concat(item_name separator ', ') as items
from buckets b
where b.id = (select max(b2.id) from buckets b2 where b2.item_name = b.item_name) and
      b.action <> 'remove'
group by bucketname;
```

Comment: Don't you need to count the insert's and remove's?

Comment: @jarlh . . . I don't think so.  Or, at least, the question is asking for the most recent status.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think we need to add a `group by b2.bucketname` in the sub-query items are not unique per bucket.
The query runs slow (on 15 buckets and about 2000 records it takes 2.5 seconds), can it be improved?

Comment: An index on `buckets(item_name, id)` should help performance.